# How to use select query with 3 join tables to load data into DataGridView and TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2017

I tried this to load data into a DataGridView and TextBoxes.But an error said "ambiguous column name PO_No". So how to solve this

```
public void loadPOCarttable()
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();

        try
        {
            con.sqlquery("SELECT p.PO_No,p.Supplier_ID,p.Date,p.RequiredDate,p.GrandTotal,b.BookName,c.ISBN_No,c.OrderQuantity,c.UnitPrice,c.Total FROM  TBL_PO_Cart AS c INNER JOIN TBL_Book AS b ON c.ISBN_No = b.ISBN_No INNER JOIN TBL_PO AS p ON c.PO_No=p.PO_No where PO_No='" + cmbPO.Text + "'");
            con.mysqlconnection();
            con.datatable();
            con.dataread();             
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            while (con.datareader.Read())
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
                row.Cells[0].Value = con.datareader["BookName"].ToString();
                row.Cells[1].Value = con.datareader["ISBN_No"].ToString();
                row.Cells[2].Value = con.datareader["OrderQuantity"].ToString();
                row.Cells[3].Value = con.datareader["UnitPrice"].ToString();
                row.Cells[4].Value = con.datareader["Total"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(con.cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                txtPONo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                cmbsupID.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                date1.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                requireddate.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
                txtgrandTotal.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I tried above code.But didn't work.So please anybody can me tell how to load 3 tables data into DataGridView and several TextBoxes to update that details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of your SQL statement has `PO_No=` without a table alias prefixed to it. When the Sql statement runs, Sql Server doesn't know if you want to use the table `TBL_PO` or `TBL_PO_Cart`.

To fix it, put the appropriate table prefix of `p` or `c` depending on which one you want to filter by.